# Controller parameters format

Tags: c#, rest, controller, asp.net-core-webapi

A thirdparty is calling the following URI but I'm unable to retreive the parameters :
http://host:port/#property1=abc&property2=123

I created an AspNetCore WebApi controller with an empty controller name and an empty route name.
So far, I can receive the call but I'm unable to read the property1 and property2.

Those are not parameters from body, nor from Route/Query.
Last resort would be to retreive the full received URI and parse it with a regex but I'm also not able to (I tried to setup an ActionFilterAttribute but I'm stuck getting the called URI).

So far this is exceeding my webapi knowledge.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No... hash parameters are not sent so server and is only used by the browser.

You can use ? Instead of # to get it on the server.

Comment: I know I have to "replace" # by ? to be able to retreive parameters but I don't handle this thirdparty uri. That's why I explained I failed to intercept the called uri to tweak it (but it seems wrong)

Comment: I understand your question but There is no way to intercept that.

Comment: The hash values are not sent to the server, so there is no chance you can get it by any tweak on the server side